# how do I read session content xml format with php5

Tags: php, xml, session

I need to read session content with php.
The session is created by a shopping cart script called easybasket and I need to extract data stored in the session, so I can save into MySql table. It seems that the data is stored in XML format. Here is the content of my session:

```
array (size=3)
'username' => string 'test@gmail.com' (length=21)
'nombre' => string 'Joe Smith' (length=16)
'basket' => string '<basket version="1.0" timestamp="2013-05-04T12:58:37+00:00">
<items count="2" quantity="4" subtotal="1460" postage="0" total="1460" paypal="yes"     google="no">
<item unit-price="380.00" quantity="2" subtotal="760" postage="0" total="760">
  <title>DANCER CATAMARAN ADULTS</title>
  <price>380.00</price>
</item>
<item unit-price="350.00" quantity="2" subtotal="700" postage="0" total="700">
  <title>DANCER CATAMARAN CHILDREN</title>
  <price>350.00</price>
</item>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you having problem reading the XML?

Comment: Read up on SimpleXML, particularly the [basic SimpleXML usage](http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) page. If you get stuck, check existing questions here for tips. If you're still stuck, ask a specific question we can help you with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [simpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to browse the content of $_SESSION['basket']

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($_SESSION['basket']);
```

Example :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($_SESSION['basket']);
foreach( $xml->items->item as $item) {
    echo $item['quantity'] . ' - ' . $item->title . '<br>';
}
```

Output :

```
2 - DANCER CATAMARAN ADULTS
2 - DANCER CATAMARAN CHILDREN
```

Comment: Hi RafH, thank you very much, it wors for me !!

Comment: Great ! plz accept the answer to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust session array like that...

A xml injection or xml entry injection are possible now if a attacker manages to inject data into a session when the webhoster is using the same session dir for all users.

Use libxml_disable_entity_loader (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-disable-entity-loader.php) before the simpelXml to make it safe against xml entry injection